# Stock Turn : Inventory TurnOver

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to Calculate `Stock Turn = (COGS for last 12 months from Current date)/Average Inventory Cost for last 12 months)`.So my 1st step is to Calculate COGS for last 12 months(Cost of Good Sold). I am using the following Query:

> SUM( ClosingPeriod([Date].[Calendar].[Month], [Date].[Calendar].[All
>   Periods]).Lag(12):ClosingPeriod([Date].[Calendar].[Month],
>   [Date].[Calendar].[All Periods]), [Measures].[Cogs Amount])

But the Calculated Member is giving me Null results.

Please help.!!

Cheers
Rushir

Comment: My Select statement is with member measures.Cogs_last_12 as
sum(
closingperiod([Date].[Date].[Cal Month],[Date].[Date].[All]).lag(2)
: ClosingPeriod([Date].[Date].[Cal Month],[Date].[Date].[All]),
[Measures].[Cogs Amount])
select measures.Cogs_last_12 on 0
from Inventory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [ALL Periods]. You should not use that member because it is the root. 
The Lag(12) of [All Periods] doesn't exist.

Try using an specific member, something like this:

```
SUM({ClosingPeriod([Date].[Calendar].[Month], [Date].[Calendar].[2011].[11]).Lag(12):ClosingPeriod([Date].[Calendar].[Month], [Date].[Calendar].[2011].[11])}, [Measures].[Cogs Amount])
```

Or something like this:

SUM({[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(12):[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember}, [Measures].[Cogs Amount])

Comment: Hi,
   Thanks for the query.I am still having the problem. I use
SUM({[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(12):[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember}, [Measures].[Cogs Amount])
But it is giving me the same amount rather than giving me 1 year sum. My total for Cogs amount is 1,601,083.May be some thing wrong in my Date Hierarchy? I have attached pic of my Date Hierarchy. Please do have a look.Let me know if you want any other information.I am really stuck on this for last 3 weeks. Help..!!

[IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/14v5x1u.jpg[/IMG]
http://tinypic.com/r/14v5x1u/5

Comment: Could you show the mdx query? 

I think you aren't using a time member correctly. In order to use the CURRENTMEMBER function, you must indicate a member on WHERE section. 
Sample:
With Member [Measures].[Calculated 01] ....
Select 
{[Measures].[Calculated 01]} On Columns,
{...dimensions...} On Rows
From [Cube Name]
WHERE ([Date].[Date].[2011])

Comment: Hi, I am not using Where clause as its a Calculated member in Business Intelligence Development Studies it does not allow Where Clause.I am using  SUM({[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(12):[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember}, [Measures].[Cogs Amount]) . I want some thing dynamic in order to get the COGS till date from last one year.For example if today is 1st of Jan then I need the COGS amount for last year starting Jan 1st 2010 till today i.e. Jan 1st 2011.So I guess i dont need a where clause or else it will make my query Static. Is that right? Please help ..!!

Comment: I'll try to explain: the CURRENTMEMBER function returns the member than you are using in filter section. So, if you are testing your CalculatedMember on the Browse of BIDS, you must add a filter of the DATE dimension. What tool do you use? You could pass time filter like a parameter.

Comment: Hi,
   I am creating a Calculated member in BIDS and using the cube in Excel Pivot Table.